# symmetry of a square - is it possible pure geometric approach in didactics?

Tags: geometry

1. Consider a square : four points in a plane constructed with classical means (compass and straightedge). Since no point is different from others (no coordinates, no labels...) it seems that we can not define any (some) symmetry without additional mathematical structure.
2. With distance involved, the two nearest points to a given point are equivalent and so this new object has two lines of symmetry only.
3. In case all four points are taken as different we have our four lines of symmetry...

The question is : what is the best way to introduce the minimum additional mathematical structure needed, to go from 1 to 2 and from 2 to 3 without reaching to physics and other extra-mathematical illustrations (paper folding, physical rotation etc.) ? Maybe there are more than one good road to achieve this goal ? What are the key / most persistent / misconceptions in introducing symmetry of a square to elementary graders as well as the silent assumptions underlaying such introductions ?

Any reference would be very much appreciated.

---

Let me try to clarify myself.

The goal is to explain, in simple but hopefully, mathematically correct way, why and under which conditions one may say that a square has four lines of symmetry. So, let start with those four points that geometrically *define* square. They are all indistinguishable as lay on a plane. We may label them (and so make them physically distinguishable) but lets try not to step outside mathematics.  We can not rotate this "square", can not translate it - it is quite a primitive object.

Introduce, at a step No. 2, a simple metric (distance) in this set X of our four points. (map d: X x X -> R) Question: what is the most simple metric here ? The one in which the two adjacent point of any given point of our square are still indistinguishable (equivalent) and the fourth one, is the furthest one from our vantage point. Question: with this most simple metric, how many lines of symmetry does this (new) object (four points plus simple metric) has ? I say *two*, one along the diagonal and the other cutting the opposite sides at half. We can not discuss any rotation at this level as we did not have coordinates for *all* points of our plane. Now we may select another point as reference point of a coordinate system, make axes, units along these axes and label the points with coordinates in respect of this coordinate system. This is a lot of additional mathematical structure. Now we have square with distinguishable points, rotations and - voila : four lines of symmetry.

So, that is. From geometry, to metric spaces, real numbers, continuous symmetry etc. Quite a lot, i would say, to be introduced at one step to.

Key question : how to make these steps, from a most basic square (four points only) to our useful, ordinary square (with circumference and area) as simple and as precise as possible.

With regards.

Comment: Your question is quite obscure to me. First, using a compass already implies distance is involved (a compass is nothing else than an instrument that traces the set of points at the same *distance* to a given point than the *distance* separating two given points), and the very notion of square relies on distances. Second, item 2 makes no sense to me: what is "the new object" you are writing about? Third, what do you mean by "different points"? Do you mean that are made distinguishable? Or that they are not equal? Or something else? Last, your ultimate goal is not very clear to me, I must say.

Comment: thank you for helping me. I will keep here one short comment only; I am intrigued by your remark that using a compass (pure geometry) implies distance (real numbers); please clarify, as we may met at some point on this..

Comment: Sorry, but I still can't make sense out of this question. In my remark on the compass, the distance I have in mind is of course the Euclidean distance (sometimes called a metric, but the two words are only one in French and have a large intersection in mathematical English, hence a possible misunderstanding). For a discrete set such as you seem to consider in you step two, the notion of line of symmetry makes no sense. I vote to close for I don't feel your question is articulated properly in mathematical language.

Comment: if i understand you correctly, you claim that a square or a triangle, for that matter, _must_ have be defined only with full blown mathematical structure of my step 3 to be candidate for a geometric figure with a symmetry ?

Comment: You write: "So, let start with those four points that geometrically define square.".  Please clarify what definition of "square" you are using here.  You seem to be (implicitly) saying that any set of four points is a square.  Surely that's not what you mean?

Comment: I did. In point 1 of my question: i defined "square" constructively - four points put on a plane with compass and straightedge, in a classical way but without lines connecting them, without distances, perimeter, area...

Comment: I agree to close this exchange of views on this topic. Thanks to all who bothered to comment for their time. regards.

Answer (score 3):

The indistinguishability of the points is precisely the reason *why* the square has symmetries.

Let's labels one of the four points of the square $A$.  To this you object (I think, if I have understood you correctly):  "But there is no way to tell the points apart, so how do we know which one is $A$?"  And to this I respond:  "I agree that we don't know which one is $A$.  It is an arbitrary choice.  *Remember that for later.*"

Next, let's label one of the remaining three points $B$ -- but let's be sure to choose one of the points with the property that the segment joining $A$ to $B$ is one of the sides of the square, not its diagonal.  (Notice that having made a choice of $A$, we are now able to *partly distinguish* among the remaining three points, because two of them are adjacent to $A$ and the third one is diagonally across from $A$.)  We still don't have any basis for distinguishing between the two candidates for $B$, so just pick one of them arbitrarily, and *remember for later that we made this choice*.

Having chosen $A$ and $B$, let $C$ be the point diagonally across from $A$ and let $D$ be the point diagonally across from $B$.  Notice that this identification is now *unambiguous*; having chosen $A$ (arbitrarily) and $B$ (partly arbitrarily), the identification of $C$ and $D$ is now completely determined.

Now, what if two different people, looking at the same (unlabeled, "naked" square in a bare plane with no coordinates) had followed the same set of instructions above, but made different initial choices about which point to call $A$ and which point to call $B$?  Then they would have labeled the squares differently, of course.  All together there are $8$ different possible labelings they could have chosen.  Those $8$ labelings are precisely the $8$ symmetries of the square.

Comment: o.k. i think i understand your point here. 1st: Please clarify 'opposite' (point); how to find (constructively) which of the three other points are 'opposite' to A (arbitrary chosen point) and which adjacent _if_ you have only points, no angles, no _distances_ ? 2nd: the second labeling of the "naked" square will be _exactly_ the same as the first ! The difference will pop up only if you compare the second labeling with the first one which means that the square is not _naked_ or that the points are already distinguishable. And 3rd: please try formally to define "labeling" - no chalk, no pencil

Comment: "Label" does not require an act of physical labeling, just the decision to call an arbitrarily-chosen member of a set by a generic name.  "There are three elements in a set; call one of them $x$" is a perfectly reasonable mathematical move.

Comment: As for your claim that two such assignments of names are "the same", the fact that the points are not **distinguishable** does not mean that they are not **distinct**.  If there are 3 points in a set, and the points are not distinguishable, there are nevertheless 3 points in the set, and 6 permutations of the set.  That is: If I decide to call one of them $A$, and one of them $B$, and one of them $C$, there are 6 different ways to do that.  There may operationally be no way to tell one such set of choices from another, but that doesn't change the fact that there *are* 6 sets of choices.

Comment: How can you even define "square" if you don't have angles or distances?  More specifically: one doesn't need to be able to assign a measurement to segments or angles, but one *does* need to be able to determine whether two segments are *congruent*, and whether two angles are *congruent* to each other.  Otherwise there is no way to tell the difference between a square and an arbitrary quadrilateral.

Comment: Finally:  Whether a given point $P$ is "opposite from $A$" or "adjacent to $A$" can be determined quite simply by checking whether the segment from $A$ to $P$ passes through the interior of the square or lies along one of its edges.  (If you don't have a sufficiently robust geometry to distinguish between "interior" and "edge", then I ask again, how can you even define "square" in the first place?)

Comment: define it constructively: those four points on a plane i get using compass and straightedge.

Comment: @dragan Please describe how you carry out the straightedge and compass construction without implicitly making reference to congruence and angles.

Comment: mweiss It seems to me that there a _lot_ of implicit references here. It is exactly what worries me. I try to hold on pure geometry as far as i can. And if i can not than make it explicit what is going on. Now, with this classical means i have two facts "angles are equal" and "sides are equal." I do not agree that we may discuss proper about _distances_ as, for me, this implies metric space (and i want to postpone including it, for now). I don't know other, more primitive expression for _angles_ to use above. That is all we have from congruence at this level.

Comment: I completely agree with all participants in this discussion that this _naked_ square is quite primitive object. But if for introducing a bit of symmetry (lines of symmetry) of square in elementary school i _have_ to introduce real line and analylsis (implicitly, i agree, via metrics in plane) the price is high, in my opinion. What do we teach pupils ? Geometry or something else ? So, i ask for a help from community - you - to help me to clarify this (implicit) mess of ideas. The situation is similar with labeling. How to label an element from an abstract set of four points ?

Comment: They are in my head only ? o.k. i can imagine them, one by one, as memory chunks and label them A, B... Even for thinking about them i have to make them distinct (and distinguishable). Only afterwards i may decide: o.k. now i will suppose that they are equivalent in respect of something, say position and so they are indistinguishable (but still distinct, as you say)... If you agree with me so far, than we have a _lot_ of implicit physics in pure geometry indeed.

Comment: Maybe i should give up of the ambition to define my "naked" four points as proper square ? After all i did construct it with compass (and this is for sure a real object). regards

Comment: I am completely supportive of the idea of avoiding (as far as reasonable) introducing a metric on your geometry -- and indeed Euclid did just fine without ever attaching a numerical "length" to a segment.  But "equal distance" *as an equivalence relation* is baked into all compass and straightedge constructions, because a compass is a device (whether physical or conceptual, it does not matter) for identifying a set of points that are all equidistant from a given one.  There is no way to talk about compass and straightedge constructions without making use of "equidistance".